# Stored procedure in SQL Server with select query then if condition and then insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure in which first select statement and depending on the selected parameter if valid, insert record in the another table else do nothing. How to write the stored procedure for this?

I have tried with stored procedure and it is executed with no errors, but when I tried to EXEC stored procedure, it doesn't do the task as written in procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CreateExpiryDocumentFollowup
    (@param INT = NULL,
     @param2 INT = NULL,
     @param3 INT = 1,
     @param4 BIT = 0,
     @followupid INT = NULL)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @param1 = [TABLE_A].[VEHICLE_ID],
        @param2 = [TABLE_A].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID],
        @followupid = [TABLE_B].[FOLLOWUP_ID]
    FROM 
        [TABLE_A]
    LEFT JOIN 
        [TABLE_B] ON [TABLE_B].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID] != [TABLE_A].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID]
    WHERE 
        [TABLE_A].[STATUS] = 1;

    IF @followupid = NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [TABLE_B] (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, VALUE_4)
        VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4)
    END
END
GO
```

I expect the record to insert in the `TABLE_B` if `@followupid is null`. The `@followupid` is null as I executed the select statement only. But while executing whole stored procedure it will return the result 0 row which in my case should be 1. And I checked the table as well, no any record is inserted but stored procedure runs successfully.

Comment: `@followupid = null` is wrong it should be `@followupid IS NULL`. Also that won't work as expected if you have more than 1 row with `[TABLE_A].[STATUS] = 1`

Comment: "`[TABLE_B].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID] != [TABLE_A].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID]`" also looks suspicious. Likely you meant `[TABLE_B].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID] = [TABLE_A].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID]`.

Comment: *" it doesn't do the task as written in procedure."* The SQL will do exactly as it's written; but what you think you've written and what you have are obviously different.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I suspect that a left join on != is going to return a lot of records!  I think you mean =.

Comment: @Sami : Yes you are right. It helped me. And as you had said, it doesn't work for more than 1 row. How to write procedure for that case?

Comment: To add to @Sami 's comment, if `@followupid = null` is working as you expect, this means you have `ANSI_NULLS` set to off. This is deprecated and will stop working in a future version of SQL Server. YOu should stop using `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` as soon as you can and change to proper `NULL` logic.

Comment: Use CTE to store the data that has followupid null and then insert it into table B. Also declare your parameters with declare if you are not going to pass them in your stored procedure.

Comment: A CTE doesn't "store" any information @ClaudioCorchez ; It's an expression, not an object.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @Larnu , https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez I know what a CTE Is, that's why i corrected you/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would write it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CreateExpiryDocumentFollowup
(
    --@param1 int = null -- this is no longer needed
    --@param2 int = null -- this is no longer needed
    @param3 int = 1,
    @param4 bit = 0
    --,@followupid int = null -- -- this is no longer needed
)
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [TABLE_B] (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, VALUE_4)
    SELECT [TABLE_A].[VEHICLE_ID], [TABLE_A].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID], @param3, @param4
    FROM [TABLE_A]
    LEFT JOIN [TABLE_B] 
        -- as stated in the comments to the questions, 
        -- Shouldn't this condition be `=` instead of `!=`?
        ON [TABLE_B].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID] != [TABLE_A].[VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_ID]
    WHERE [TABLE_A].[STATUS] = 1
    AND [TABLE_B].[FOLLOWUP_ID] IS NULL

END
GO
```

Instead of first selecting and then inserting, you can do an `insert...select` operation which leads to a shorter, more readable code.
This way, if the select statement doesn't return any rows, nothing gets inserted into the target table.

Also, you can't use equality operators on `NULL` in SQL. Instead, you can only use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` (Or `NOT IS NULL` if you like that better).

Please note that if the select statement returns more than one row, all of them will be inserted into the target table.